# Get Visual Studio build progress in an extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension and I need to display a new progress bar showing the build progress (not TFS build). I've found a code that counts the number of projects inside the solution to calculate the percentage of built projects, however, if I choose to rebuild a project that has project references, it is not able to get the progress. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think VS2013 SDK samples contains what you want. Have you taken a look at that?

[Build Progress Bar - VS 2013](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Build-Progress-Bar-VS-2013-35f02ee7)

> A Visual Studio Package which provides a new tool window called "Build
>   Progress" which displays a WPF ProgressBar indicating percentage
>   completion of the current solution build.